# Searching in array of objects

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, arraylist, nspredicate

I have array of objects(users).

I have problem where this array contains same objects.

This objects have ids.

I want to search in this array for objects with same id and have results in array.

What is the best way to do it?

Or maybe there is a way to create NSSet based on that ids? This will be the best way. Or may be I can use predicate here or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with he predicate like this:

```
NSArray *arr = @[a,b,c];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id == %@),theIdYouAreLookingFor];
arr  = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and then you ask if the results were empty.

I think a must efficient way to do it is just hold a NSDictionary instead of NSArray and once you enter a new entry look if it's exist in the dictionary - if it's not create it and add it - if it is just add it. 
The dictionary should be like that:
  key: objectID
  value: array of object with the given id.

Comment: As I understood, the problem is not to find elements with any particular id but filter out all elements with duplicated ids.

Comment: So.. for the first solution you simply ask if the array after the predicate return any results (if you didn't exclude the current object you compare with the array should be empty, or if you didn't it has to have one result, i.e the object itself). fAs for the other solution you're just filtering the dictionary by asking if the value array has more than one object

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways:

1. Override `isEqual` in class for array's objects and compare objects' ids in this method, then create `NSSet` using the `[NSSet setWithArray:]` method.
2. If you can't override the `isEqual` method for objects from the array then sort the array using objects' ids, iterate through the sorted array and add elements to a resulting `NSArray` (or `NSSet`) when ids of current and previous elements are not the same.